# Parsing contents of table

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am having such a hard time figuring out why this does not work. The URL is this:
https://www.cmlviz.com/pivot-points/GOOG

I want to parse the table with the checkboxes, its class name is "updatable" with an ID of "pivot_data_grid". What am I doing wrong? This is driving me crazy! I just want to get the value of each row in the table along with the title (ex: 5-day Exponential Moving Average). Thank you for any help

```
        string url = "https://www.cmlviz.com/pivot-points/{symbol}".Replace("{symbol}", symbol);

        HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(url);
        //var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id=pivot_data_grid]/table");
        var table = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='updatable']");
        var table = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='updatable']/table");
```

Comment: the website is loaded via `JavaScript` so you will need to render it. you can use `Selenium` or just the `XHR` request along with `pandas` (or whatever you have in c# to read html table) to read the table. something like https://www.cmlviz.com/inc/pivot-points.php?ticker=GOOG&key=57f42fb7382e7ef5679277fb3c2431c1 . i can solve this with `Python`, let me know if you want the solution by Python. also i think that you can do it via `c#`

Comment: https://www.cmlviz.com/get_live_quotes.php?tickers=GOOGL

Comment: Wow dude! Ok I never ventured this far but a example would be nice if you don't mind sharing your python solution..also how the heck did you find those other uri's? amazing

Comment: check my answer below, and regarding how to find the urls, it's via your browser dev-tools and checking network-tab to see which requests has been made. since i don't know your expected output. i posted an answer for you including all output.

Comment: thats awesome. I accepted your answer too. this really helps me, I will re-write it in c#. appreciate it alot

Comment: The main problem it that you're trying to load an Html Document from a file. The `div` element (a `div`, not a `table`) will of course be nonexistent. Use `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument webDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);` instead and parse the `body` node. It's all there. If the WebSite provides an API, try to query it.

Comment: Would that render the javascript output (table with the values)? I think I tried this way as well, tried a lot of things at this point hah

Comment: Most probably not. The inner container (`<div class="panels" style="">`) is filled with 3 main javascript functions. It will be empty when loaded this way. You can use a WebBrowser class and navigate to that page, then use the classic methods: `GetElementById()`, `GetElementsByTagName()` etc, provided by the standard HtmlDocument object.

Comment: btw took me no more than 5min once I had that other url that you provided @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη

Comment: @KPS cool yea :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.cmlviz.com/inc/pivot-points.php?ticker=GOOG&key=57f42fb7382e7ef5679277fb3c2431c1")


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'updatable'}):
    print(item.get_text("\n", strip=True))
```

Output:

```
Alphabet Inc Real-time Moving Average Pivot Points
Current Price
$
1,351.22
-1.27 Fibonacci Extension
$711.74
52 Week Low
$977.66
Select MAs for your chart:
5-day Exponential Moving Average
$
1,351.99
8-day Exponential Moving Average
$
1,349.83
10-day Exponential Moving Average
$
1,347.71
13-day Exponential Moving Average
$
1,344.21
21-day Exponential Moving Average
$
1,334.60
50-day Simple Moving Average
$
1,300.28
200-day Simple Moving Average
$
1,206.62
.382 Fibonacci Retracement
$1,216.62
.50 Fibonacci Retracement
$1,171.00
.618 Fibonacci Retracement
$1,125.37
52 Week High
$1364.33
1.27 Fibonacci Extension
$1,735.43
RSI 20
63.20
```